# Pass a variable from one foreach loop to another

Tags: php

I have this code that i am using to iterate some data that i selected from the database

```
 public function trade_profit_cron(){
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

   $loss_account = 0;

   $query = $this->db->query("select trade_pool_hash from live_trading group by trade_pool_hash");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
        $trade_pool_hash = $row->trade_pool_hash;

$query_pool_loss = $this->db->query("select sum(trade_consequence) as total_loss from live_trading where trade_status = 'LOSS' and trade_pool_hash = '$trade_pool_hash'");
$query_pool_profit = $this->db->query("select * from live_trading where trade_status = 'WIN' and trade_pool_hash = '$trade_pool_hash'");

        if ($query_pool_loss->num_rows() > 0)
            {
               foreach ($query_pool_loss->result() as $row2)
                {
                $total_loss = $row2->total_loss;
                $total_loss_float = floatval($total_loss);
                $loss_account = $total_loss_float + $loss_account;
                $this->session->set_userdata('loss_account', $loss_account);

                echo $this->session->userdata('loss_account').'<br/>';


                //Profit Divide

                if ($query_pool_profit->num_rows() > 0)
            {
               foreach ($query_pool_profit->result() as $row)
                {

                //echo $loss_account.'<br/>';


                }

            }

                }

            }

        }

    }
    //echo $this->session->userdata('loss_account');
 }
```

I am selecting data in the outer loop and using some data to loop the inner loop. I need now to get the sum of a a field in the inner loop and i indeed get it. However, since i am inside a loop, what is displayed is multiple values of my sum.

I need the sum as a single digit so that i may pass it to the other loop?.

The sum is 43.5 but this is what i get

```
43
43
43
43
43
43
43
43
43.5
43.5
43.5
```

instead. How can i display one value for the sum?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get you right, you want to get the sum of data in a loop. All you need to do is have your echo outside the loop, the reason for this is that each time the loop run through an `echo` statement, it prints it. So, you might want to comment out the `echo` statement inside your `foreach` or you move it to outside the loop. A simple example will be:

```
$sum = 0;
$data = [1,2,3,4,5];

foreach($data as $val) {
    $sum += $val;
}

echo $sum;
```

Your code sample:

```
public function trade_profit_cron(){
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST");
   header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

   $loss_account = 0;

   $query = $this->db->query("select trade_pool_hash from live_trading group by trade_pool_hash");

   if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
           $trade_pool_hash = $row->trade_pool_hash;
           $query_pool_loss = $this->db->query("select sum(trade_consequence) as total_loss from live_trading where trade_status = 'LOSS' and trade_pool_hash = '$trade_pool_hash'");
           $query_pool_profit = $this->db->query("select * from live_trading where trade_status = 'WIN' and trade_pool_hash = '$trade_pool_hash'");

            if ($query_pool_loss->num_rows() > 0) {
               foreach ($query_pool_loss->result() as $row2) {
                   $total_loss = $row2->total_loss;
                   $total_loss_float = floatval($total_loss);
                   $loss_account = $total_loss_float + $loss_account;
               }
            }
            //Profit Divide
            if ($query_pool_profit->num_rows() > 0) {
               foreach ($query_pool_profit->result() as $row) {
                   //echo $loss_account.'<br/>';
               }
            }
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata('loss_account', $loss_account);

        echo $loss_account;//return $loss_account
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution answers what OP is asking about. His issue sits on getting a random .5 from somwhere I believe. Regardless, you should have a look at this neat function called [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) it may save you some time next time you're running a calculation like that

Comment: I know how nice and neat array_sum is but just showing example based on the question asked.